# Python statement merge

Tags: python

I have a standard format letter(in txt format) and within it I want to replace some words(keywords) with the words I have created in a separate wordlist.

to visualise my letter is:

```
Dear [name],
 
I have b-day party on [date] at [venue]
please be there @ [time]
 
Sincerely,
```

the following is the file that I would like to replace:

```
Mary
12.02.2022
Soho House
08.00pm
```

so Mary would be seen on the [name] and 12.02.2022 is seen on the [date] such as:

Dear Mary,
I have a b-day party on 12.02.2022 xxxx

Following code didnot work. Could you please support how to solve this issue?

```
import keyword
 
placeholder1="[name]"
placeholder2="[date]"
placeholder3="[venue]"
placeholder4="[time]"
 
 
with open("occurence.txt") as letter:
    keyref=letter.readlines()
 
 
with open("sample_letter.txt") as target:
    target_contents=target.read()
 
 
 
for name in keyref:
    word1=target_contents.replace(placeholder1,name)
 
 
for date in keyref:
    word2 = target_contents.replace(placeholder2, date)
 
 
print(word1)
print(word2)
```

Comment: Didn't work *how*? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel. I suggest that you consider using [Template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) from the `string` module. Another viable possibility would be to use so-called "f-strings" — see [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to import keywords use variables instead. Write things and that. I don't think it will work that way. Please sort it out nicely. You can also make it so that it is an input but this is what I wrote:

```
name = 'name'
date = 'date'
venue = 'venue'
time = 'time'

print("Dear ",name + "\nI have b-day party on ",date + "at ",venue +
"please be there @",time + "\nSincerely,"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Siwan SR, thank you for your response. What I actually need is to store keywords_list in a separate file and read them from that file and replace them where necessary in my main file. Your solution is perfectly fine but doesnot work for me.